# 'breadth-having'

Tags: meaning

I'm english learner, and I would like to know the word 'breadth-having''s meaning.

My english textbook says "Another way extroverts and introverts are different involves the concept of breadth and depth. By and large, extroverts like breadth-having lots of friends and experiences.~~'

How can I understand this word 'breadth-have'? I can't find it even in english-english dictionary ㅠㅠ please help me.

Comment: The - (hyphen) is not forming a compound word, it is used like a comma, so it should read "...like breadth, having"

Comment: For the passage to make sense it should be a dash, with a space before and after, which is used like a semicolon, to introduce the explanation of the term 'breadth'.

Comment: *By and large, extroverts like breadth–having lots of friends and experiences.*

Comment: Clare, was that what you really meant? On my that's some kind of un-spaced hyphen…